# Weka Character Level CNN

Tags: nlp, cnn, weka

I am wanting to use a character level CNN to classify a heap of documents based on the century which they are from. I am having difficulties finding any resources on how to do character level classification in WEKA and was wondering whether anyone has any experience with this. I am using the wekadeeplearning4j package but I can't seem to figure out how their CNN text iterator can work with characters instead of embeddings. I would greatly appreciate any help.